# Javascript string properties and for of?

Tags: javascript, string

I have written the following code, but I am not clear on how the obj parameter is linked to the actual members object to return key value that are sting only?

Could someone explain the relationship between `showProperties(obj)` and `showProperties(member)`?

```
const member = {
  name: 'name',
  surname: 'surname',
  age: 30
};

showProperties(member);

function showProperties(obj) {
  for (let key in obj)
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'string')
      console.log(key, obj[key]);
};
```

Comment: https://javascript.info/function-basics#parameters

Answer (score 0):

The one is a function definition the other is the invocation of the function

```js
const member = {
  name: 'name',
  surname: 'surname',
  age: 30
};
//This calls the function 
showProperties(member);


// This is the function to iterate over the JavaScript Object
function showProperties(obj) {
  for (let key in obj)
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'string')
      console.log(key, obj[key]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an important question in understanding JavaScript. Let's discuss what happens when you create the `member` object and then what happens when you pass `member` to the `showProperties` function.

Consider the following code:

```
const member = {
  name: 'name',
  surname: 'surname',
  age: 30
};
```

What's going on here is you are creating the object `{ name: 'name', surname: 'surname', age: 30 }` in memory and then having the variable `member` reference that object in memory.

Now, you call `showProperties(member)`. In the `showProperties` function, `obj` now points to the same object in memory that `member` points to. This is important because any mutation you perform on `obj` within your function will be performed on the object that `member` is pointing to (there is only one object).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this. Appreciate it!